# Weird JSON to CSV conversion

Tags: python, json, csv, ubuntu

I have data of approx 700 MB in the form of:

```
{"hash":"b2f405b1589efd8b013869d1d5e605367643db20844572ea7bf788f8575c38d6","block_timestamp":"2020-05-08 13:21:33 UTC","addresses":["3E17PiWGJqP8945KRZHuPdsFSU59othGEQ"]}
{"hash":"6609073b5979d768933f2ea7d4f1723d07c03a3e08f48adff21b9f1d79cee164","block_timestamp":"2020-05-08 13:39:39 UTC","addresses":["3CfewsC7Xjp2oJSBT2zUQkYSXfzo2nuGha"]}
{"hash":"5c7d95f903ea505d9ab82d1090944780c00e91d343ae66e94610bff1d614f90f","block_timestamp":"2020-04-05 23:19:30 UTC","addresses":["1ztVt2xwNwgzH3W9SJ2nMgPMuZpUg8m5w"]}
{"hash":"7eb120e9b50dbc25f13415b3c899efe2cfaf870a7f49995aa6e3b672a1992e56","block_timestamp":"2020-04-08 05:41:51 UTC","addresses":["1HckjUpRGcrrRAtFaaCAUaGjsPx9oYmLaZ"]}
{"hash":"be202b37aa218461827138ff32e3dfa74945808f3ecb574fb5287e99c8ae6a33","block_timestamp":"2020-04-04 09:53:28 UTC","addresses":["3Jk8HaC8Sjq6Ufig9NkWFoFcfzC5a3CNyL"]}
```

Currently I have kept this data in a JSON file format. I want to convert it to csv. Doing it through common python and BASH methods does not give me proper result.(Please note that there is no comma between two rows, its just a newline)

I want it to be in a CSV with headers: hash, block_timestamp and addresses. How do I do so?

Comment: Can you share what you tried in python or BASH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. Assuming that there is only one address in every `addresses` key of the JSON.

**NOTE:** As Python will load every line at a time so it can handle big data if you read line-by-line.

```
import json
fp = open("input.txt", "r")
ofp = open("output.txt", "w")

ofp.write("hash,block_timestamp,addresses\n")
for line in fp:
  json_obj = json.loads(line)
  # print(json_obj)
  ofp.write(json_obj["hash"] + "," + json_obj["block_timestamp"] + "," + json_obj["addresses"][0] + "\n")

fp.close()
ofp.close()

fp = open("output.txt")
for line in fp:
  print(line)
```

Output:

```
hash,block_timestamp,addresses
b2f405b1589efd8b013869d1d5e605367643db20844572ea7bf788f8575c38d6,2020-05-08 13:21:33 UTC,3E17PiWGJqP8945KRZHuPdsFSU59othGEQ
6609073b5979d768933f2ea7d4f1723d07c03a3e08f48adff21b9f1d79cee164,2020-05-08 13:39:39 UTC,3CfewsC7Xjp2oJSBT2zUQkYSXfzo2nuGha
5c7d95f903ea505d9ab82d1090944780c00e91d343ae66e94610bff1d614f90f,2020-04-05 23:19:30 UTC,1ztVt2xwNwgzH3W9SJ2nMgPMuZpUg8m5w
7eb120e9b50dbc25f13415b3c899efe2cfaf870a7f49995aa6e3b672a1992e56,2020-04-08 05:41:51 UTC,1HckjUpRGcrrRAtFaaCAUaGjsPx9oYmLaZ
be202b37aa218461827138ff32e3dfa74945808f3ecb574fb5287e99c8ae6a33,2020-04-04 09:53:28 UTC,3Jk8HaC8Sjq6Ufig9NkWFoFcfzC5a3CNyL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You nailed it!!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to do that in a single line of bash. For example, if your file is called `tt`, just run:

```
cat tt | sed -e "s/:/,/g" | awk -F"," '{print $2 "," $4 "," $6}'
```

Alternatively, if you really want to do it in Python, read the file line by line, use `json.loads` to parse each line, and then print the line in a CSV format (this is what ranka47 is doing in his / her answer). The catch - it's much slower for large files.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by deserialising each line and passing the resulting `dict` to [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.json') as jf, open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    # Handle the first row individually because we need to work out the
    # column headings
    line = next(jf)
    dict_ = json.loads(line)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, dict_.keys())
    writer.writerow(dict_)
    # Loop through the rest of the file
    for line in jf:
        dict_ = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow(dict_)
```

If you don't want a header row, the code can be simplified to use a [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

```
with open('data.json') as jf, open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in jf:
        dict_ = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow(dict_.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pandas` then you can do the following:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


contents = [json.loads(line) for line in open("input.txt", 'r')]
df = pd.DataFrame(contents)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score -3):

In fact, my idea, the simplest way is:
- opening the file with a power editor, since your file size is big.
- replace all dict keys with empty text, for example: replace <"hash":> with empty...
- replace {, }, [, ] with empty text also.
- The left part are good CSV format.

Haha, don't need code.